# Pass multiple params with same key with different value + AFnetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, afnetworking-2

I want to pass multiple params with same key with different values using AFNetworking, check below my code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic setValue:@"1" forKey:@"UserID"];
[dic setValue:@"12" forKey:@"catID[]"];
[dic setValue:@"13" forKey:@"catID[]"];
[dic setValue:@"14" forKey:@"catID[]"];
```

- In iOS using NSMutableDictionary can't pass multiple params with same key (POST Method). 
  --> Question :- is there any other way to pass multiple params with same key?
- I am using AFNetworking in my app. any suggestion?

Comment: why don't you use array of catID ? I guess AFNetworking has support for this

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dic setValue:@"1" forKey:@"UserID"];

NSMutableArray *catID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[catID addObject:@"12"];
[catID addObject:@"13"];
[catID addObject:@"14"];

[dic setObject:catID forKey:@"catID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the API of AFN:

```
  (NSURLSessionDataTask *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                    parameters:(id)parameters
     constructingBodyWithBlock:(void (^)(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData))block
                      progress:(nullable void (^)(NSProgress * _Nonnull))uploadProgress
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
```

You can look the below picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nyg0.png)